# Question about number of non equivalent colourings of corners of a regular tetrahedron with k colours

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coloring, polya-counting-theory

Due to Covid -19 , in our university quizzes are held online and it's hard to ask questions.

3 Days back in my Combinatorics quiz this question was asked on which I am struck. I couldn't solve it in the time alloted and struggled to find a proper strategy.

Question is ->Determine the number of non equivalent colourings of the corners of regular tetrahedron with k different colours.

> My attempt -> I am trying to solve it by Burnside Theorem ( Number of non equivalent colourings in C are given by N(G, C) = 1/ |G| $\sum_{f \epsilon G } | C(f) | $. [C(f) = set of all colourings in C that are fixed by f ]

Group of permutations is  $S_4$ and all$ (k^4)$ will be fixed by identity . But I am not able to think how to find colourings fixed by each permutation caused due to rotations and reflections. I have done it for pentagon which was easy.

> Can someone please tell a way on how to efficiently and elegentally compute the value of C(f) in case of rotations and reflections.

I will be really thankful for the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric group is $S_4$ with $4!=24$ elements:

- 6 with cycle structure $(abcd)$ then $C(f)=k$;
- 8 with cycle structure $(abc)(d)$ then $C(f)=k^2$;
- 3 with cycle structure $(ab)(cd)$ then $C(f)=k^2$;
- 6 with cycle structure $(ab)(c)(d)$ then $C(f)=k^3$;
- 1 with cycle structure $(a)(b)(c)(d)$ then $C(f)=k^4$.

It follows that
$$N(G, C)=\frac{6k+(8+3)k^2+6k^3+k^4}{24}=\frac{(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)k}{4!}=\binom{k+3}{4}.$$

Comment: @ Robert Z in the cyclic structure (abc ) (d) is C(f) =$k^2$ due to the fact assigning same color to (abc) so k choices and assiginging a color to (d)  so k choices ?  So, it means that for (d) there must be k -1 choices instead of k otherwise I could get the same colour as chosen for (abc) which would give me transposition (abcd) as I have same colour on all 4 vertices so, how can I distinguish whether d is moving or not so if all 4 vertices have same colour then I think (abc) d = (abcd) . So, I think in second case answer should be k × k-1 instead of k × k? What di you think?

Comment: @YannicMuller I think that $C(f) =k^2$ is correct. The configuration with the same color on all the vertices is fixed for all permutations. Moreover if $k=1$ we have that $C(f) =1$ (not $0$) for any permutation $f$.

Answer (score 3):

As the symmetry group of the tetrahedron is $S_4$, colourings are already equivalent if they use the same colours the same number of times. Thus we have

- $k$ colourings of type $(a,a,a,a)$,
- $k\cdot(k-1)$ colourings of type $(a,a,a,b)$,
- $k\choose 2$ colourings of type $(a,a,b,b)$,
- $k\cdot{k-1\choose 2}$ colourings of type $(a,a,b,c)$,
- $k\choose 4$ colourings of type $(a,b,c,d){}$.

Comment: I think answer of Robert Z is right? What do you think ? Can you explain what mistake he is making or why your answer is correct. (Ignore the comment I made on this answer) .

Comment: @YannicMuller  Hagen von Eitzen's answer is correct too. The final result is the same. (+1)